# Example of irrational number with a pattern in digits

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

Suppose I created the following random number generator.

A trusted person choose a irrational number. That can easily defined and computed by a computer. Like square root of a prime.

Every time the random number generator is called it calculate the first digit, then the second digit and it goes on.

On a given moment the random number generator is on digit N. An attacker saw the last M digits. (M < N)

Can you give me an example of a bad choice of irrational number that creates a pattern that is easy to guess some or all next numbers without knowing the number? (Only the last M digits is allowed to use in build the pattern)

Comment: $3.1415926\dots$ is easy to guess, I think

Comment: Are you a "bad choice" would be if digit $N+1$ is a function of digits $N-M+1, \dots, N$?  By pigeonhole some sequence of $M$ digits must eventually repeat, and then the digits repeat from then on, so the number is rational.

Comment: If you get get the next digit from the previous $M$ then the sequence is periodic and hence you have a rational.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$0.1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950\ldots$

Comment: Cute............

Comment: Until you get to the place where the blocks start to have length $M.$ Then you get no information.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the statement of the question, whether we are to take $M$ as fixed. If $M$ is allowed to increase with $N$, your comment, @Aaron, does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear if $M$ is fixed or grows with $N$ and , if the latter, how. But under most scenarios, for example $M=\lfloor \sqrt{N}\rfloor,$ guessing the next decimal digit for something like $\sum_{n=5}^{\infty} 10^{-n^n}$ would be correct with high probability. This is predicated on there being a best guess for the next member of $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,?$.